# Cannot interfere with the TypeError

Tags: python, for-loop, integer, typeerror, except

I am consciously trying to make a mistake to use 'except' statement so that I can interfere with the expected error.

```
    a = 1
    for i in a:
        try:
            print(a*a)
        except TypeError:
            print("Hata")
```

I want to run an integer with a 'for' loop and interfere with the 'TypeError' but, somehow, I cannot trigger 'try' statement and "except" statement cannot be triggered, either. As I couldn't understand the reason, I need some help. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Integers are not iterable so your type error will occur before your try block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'int`' object is not iterable. If you want to check custom `TypeError` then use for loop in `try` and then raise `TypeError`

```
a = 1
try:
    for i in a:
        print(a*a)
except TypeError:
    print("Hata")
```